# R pasting over n values

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, paste

I just started learning R and somehow this doesn't make sense to me.

```
createVector3  = function(label, n) {
    # Implement this function body so that it returns
    # the character vector (label 1, label 2, ..., label n), where
    # label is a string and n is an integer.
   for (i in n) {paste("label", i, sep = " ")}
   }
```

I know I'm supposed to do a for loop, but I just can't see what to put in it, since n is not a string. Sorry if this sounds really dumb.

Answer (score 1):

If it needs to be for loop then:

```
createVector3  = function(label, n) {
  # Implement this function body so that it returns
  # the character vector (label 1, label 2, ..., label n), where
  # label is a string and n is an integer.
  res <- vector(length=n)
  for (i in 1:n) {res[i] <- paste(label, i, sep = " ")}
  return(res)
}
```

In a for loop you always need to assign the output of each cycle into an object. Note that I didn't add label in quotes because then it become a string "label" and never uses the label string that your pass in from calling the function.

But you don't need to make a function for that, this does the same thing:

```
paste("label",1:9,sep=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Not to take away from the answer by @JeremyS at all.  His answer is exactly what you want.  But, if you go ahead and create the function without the loop, you can go even further than the bare minimum with it by experimenting with the `apply` functions and create objects with your function (and perhaps impress your teacher in the process).

Here are a few examples.

```
> createVector3  <- function(label, n) {
      res <- paste(label, 1:n, sep = " ")
      return(res)
  }

> createVector3("label", 5)
## [1] "label 1" "label 2" "label 3" "label 4" "label 5"

> sapply(c("lab", "label", "variable"), function(x) createVector3(x, 5))
##      lab     label     variable    
## [1,] "lab 1" "label 1" "variable 1"
## [2,] "lab 2" "label 2" "variable 2"
## [3,] "lab 3" "label 3" "variable 3"
## [4,] "lab 4" "label 4" "variable 4"
## [5,] "lab 5" "label 5" "variable 5"

> mapply(createVector3, c("lab", "label", "variable"), 1:3)
## $lab
## [1] "lab 1"

## $label
## [1] "label 1" "label 2"

## $variable
## [1] "variable 1" "variable 2" "variable 3"

> mat <- matrix(c(1:30), nrow = 5, ncol = 3)
> colnames(mat) <- createVector3("Col", 3)
> rownames(mat) <- createVector3("Row", 5)
> mat
##       Col 1 Col 2 Col 3
## Row 1     1     6    11
## Row 2     2     7    12
## Row 3     3     8    13
## Row 4     4     9    14
## Row 5     5    10    15
```